# Function call in if statement without parentheses

Tags: c, syntax

Recent versions of gcc and clang on Fedora Linux compile the following program without error:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char c = 'a';
    if islower(c)
        printf("%d", c);
    else
        printf("%c", c);
    return 0;
}
```

This is with gcc 4.7.2 and clang 3.0. On my Mac, in contrast, both gcc 4.2.1 and Apple clang 4.1 complain about missing parentheses in the "if islower(c)" line, as expected. In all cases, I ran the compilers with "-std=c99".

Is this a bug in recent versions of gcc and clang, a quirk in the C language, or something else? The C99 standard (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf p. 133) appears to mandate parentheses around if expressions in all cases.

Comment: Will it compile `if 42 printf("42!\n");`? If it does, it's an interesting take on expressions. Formally, if we forget about `if`, `42` and `(42)` are identical. Ditto with `islower(c)` and `(islower(c))`.

Comment: Alexey, that's not quite true, since the C grammar requires parentheses in this particular context. It just so happens that the parentheses are here supplied by a macro.

Comment: Jelle, that's why I said "it's an interesting take on expressions" because to the best of my knowledge the parens are required.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just looked through the `ctype.h` file located in `/usr/include/ctype.h` and found the following definition for `islower`:

```
#define islower(c)  __isctype((c), _ISlower)
```

Going to the definition for `__isctype()` I find:

```
#define __isctype(c, type) \
  ((*__ctype_b_loc())[(int) (c)] & (unsigned short int) type)
```

So your code `if islower(c)` expands to:

```
if ((*__ctype_b_loc())[(int) (c)] & (unsigned short int) _ISlower)
```

Which, as unwind said, added the parenthesis during expansion.

Comment: unwind and you are right, thanks! I should have guessed that that was the case. gcc -E yields "if ((*__ctype_b_loc ())[(int) ((m))] & (unsigned short int) _ISalpha)", as you said.

Answer (score 13):

It's likely that `islower()` is a macro, and that the expansion adds the parenthesis.

Post the pre-processed output from GCC, which you can get by compiling with the `-E` option.